# Finding all solutions to an equation in complex numbers!

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, roots

Find all solutions to the equation,
$$(\omega^2+1)^4=\omega$$
In complex numbers!

---

I tried the substitution $\omega=z^4$ but wasn't helpful...and the equation becomes more complicated by this way!

Comment: [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%CF%89^2%2B1%29^4%3D%CF%89) suggests that only two of the eight roots have 'nice' forms. Were you expecting them all to have 'nice' forms?

Answer (score 2):

If you take the fourth root of each side:
$$\begin{align}
&\omega^2+1=\omega^{\frac{1}{4}} \\
\iff &z^8+1=z \\
\iff &z^8-z+1=0 \\
\iff &(z^2-z+1)(z^6+z^5-z^3-z^2+1) =0
\end{align}$$
Hope this helps.